# i want to fetch specific todo item but it gives me unauthorized

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, rtk-query

I have a simple todo app with an authentication system while the user login endpoint fetches his todos list but after the user signs, there is an error in the backend
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

please I need help to fix this issue.

endpoint controller code

```
export const getUserTodos = asyncHandler(
  async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { authorId } = req.body;

    if (!authorId) res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });

    const todos = await prisma.todo.findMany({
      where: { authorId },
    });
    if (!todos) res.status(204).json({ message: 'there are not todos yet!' });

    res.status(200).json(todos);
  }
);
```

todoApiSlice frontend code

```
getUserTodos: build.query<Todo[], { authorId: number }>({
      query: ({ authorId }) => ({
        url: '/api/todos',
      }),
      async onQueryStarted(arg, api) {
        console.log(arg);
      },
      providesTags: result =>
        result
          ? [
              ...result.map(({ id }) => {
                type: 'Todo' as const, id;
              }),
            ]
          : [{ type: 'Todo', id: 'LIST' }],
    }),
```

calling query hook

```
const {
      data: todos,
      isLoading,
      isSuccess,
      isError,
      error,
    } = useGetUserTodosQuery({ authorId: id });
```

Comment: How is this relevant to [tag:regex]?

Answer (score 0):

If authorId is missing, the server should only send a single response (401 Unauthorized) and not proceed to fetch and send the todos. You need to make sure your code is sending only one response per request.
Adding return statement after sending a response ensures that once a response is sent, the function exits immediately, preventing any subsequent attempts to modify the response headers or send additional responses. Try something like this,

```js
export const getUserTodos = asyncHandler(async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { authorId } = req.body;

  if (!authorId) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
  }

  const todos = await prisma.todo.findMany({
    where: { authorId },
  });

  if (!todos || todos.length === 0) {
    return res.status(204).json({ message: 'There are no todos yet!' });
  }

  res.status(200).json(todos);
});
```